# getting illegal argument exception on adding JSpinner in JTable

Tags: java, swing

so I am adding a JSpinner inside the cell of a Jtable using AbstractCellEditor and TableCellEditor classes
mt SpinnerEditor class is pretty simple and code is below :

```
public class SpinnerEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    final JSpinner spinner;
    SpinnerEditor(){
        spinner = new JSpinner();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return spinner.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        spinner.setValue(value);
        return spinner ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt){

    return true;
    }

}
```

The problem is i am getting an illegal argument Exception when i try to edit the cell by clicking on it as :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal value
    at javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(SpinnerNumberModel.java:443)
    at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:354)
    at timetablemgmt.SpinnerEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent(SpinnerEditor.java:39)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareEditor(JTable.java:5778)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editCellAt(JTable.java:3512)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.adjustSelection(BasicTableUI.java:1108)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTableUI.java:1038)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6530)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4523)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I am not able to figure out what is the problem!
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read theJSpinner API for the setValue(...) method? It explains why you get an IllegalArguementException. We don't have enough information to give you a specific answer other thatnto say the data in the table doesn't match what the spinner expects. Post a proper [mre] every time you ask a question so we know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: i have seen the example from    http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/UsingaListJSpinnerasaCellEditorinaJTableComponent.htm  and tried the exact same code even the same exception is arising

Comment: yup i have read documentation on oracle.com  :   public void setValue(Object value)

Changes current value of the model, typically this value is displayed by the editor. If the SpinnerModel implementation doesn't support the specified value then an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

This method simply delegates to the model. It is equivalent to:

 getModel().setValue(value)
 

Throws:
    IllegalArgumentException - if value isn't allowed
See Also:
    getValue(), SpinnerModel.setValue(java.lang.Object)        but why value is not supported ? value is Object value i

Comment: i just want to add JSpinner inside JTable cell please tell me how to do i have tried my above  code or please share an example link from which i can take help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should try:

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        spinner.setValue(value);
        return spinner ;
    }


public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        if(value == null)
           spinner.setValue(0);
        else
           spinner.setValue(value);
        return spinner ;
    }
```